# Sencha combo box display value issue

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

When I configure combo box I have to add following properties.I need to send selected id to back end.

```
 displayField : 'displayVlaue',
 valueField  : 'id',
```

after setting these properties I can send id to back end correctly.

but When I changed a value in combo box, it display value instead of name. but I need to display name and need to send value to back end

other thing is, this combo box is placed inside the grid column

```
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    id: 'batchClass',
    minWidth: 150,
    width: 200,
    dataIndex: 'batchClassId',
    text: 'BatchClass',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        autoRender: false,
        emptyText: 'Select Batch Class',
        size: 40,
        displayField: 'displayVlaue',
        store: 'AllBatchClassStore',
        valueField: 'id',
        valueNotFoundText: 'Refresh page and try again',
        listeners: {
            select: {
                fn: me.onComboboxSelect,
                scope: me
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you change the value? Usually this problem appears when the form is loaded...

Comment: yes, when I selected the drop down list, selected item shows its value instead of display value. seems this is a bug in extjs

Comment: Which version? And do you have a short example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I'm using sencha architecture 4.2 version